# Is HVAC device a heat pump?

Tags: heat-pump

A Florida HVAC device keeps a bank of storage units frosty in the summer time.   A wifi thermostat is desired: a determination has to be made as to whether the device is a heat pump or not.  The device is manufactured by `[International Comfort Products Model WAHL364B2][1]`  A google search was not successful in determining

1. Is the device a heatpump?  If not is it only an AC?
2. If the thermostat has a brown wire (Emergency Heat per color code convention), does this confirm the device is a heat pump?

[image]

[image]

[image]

A related question to the same system [is posted here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/158787/56573).

Comment: Can you post photos of the nameplate and/or wiring diagram for the outdoor and indoor units?

Comment: I think all the photos you posted are for the indoor unit, correct? The model numbers come up as an electric heater, and an air handler.

Answer (score 1):

The model number provided is an air handler. The "heat package" shown in your picture is a electric element heating which may or may not be installed(was not factory installed). The unit shipped with a evaporator coil installed as per the rating plate, but that didn't come charged with refrigerant. An air handler is capable of running a heat pump. The simplest way to tell if it's a heat pump is the model of the outdoor unit, without easy access to the condenser (if it's on a roof or something) check how many wires go to it from the air. Usually 2 wires go to a cooling only condenser. Sometimes 2 stage applications or onboard diagnostic require more wires. Never assume the color of the wire to correspond to any standard practice. I'm leaning towards no heat pump due to the TXV shipped with the coil. Heat pumps with TXV either need dual TXVs or a bypass check valve when reversed flow is happening. There may be some new methods being used in the southern states that I'm unaware of. I'm from Toronto and don't often deal with heat pumps as our electricity is very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely has an a/c *function* (it will cool an enclosed space using refrigerant 410A) so if it is not a heat pump, then it is an a/c.

Technically an a/c is a heat pump in that it acts to pump heat *out of* an enclosed space, but in common parlance a "heat pump" is an a/c unit which can be switched to pump heat *into* an enclosed space *using the refrigerant*.

According to the label it has a "heat package" (EHK10AKN3 P/N 327929-406) which is not further specified. This heat package could be connections and devices using the refrigerant to heat the interior space in which case it would be a heat pump (pumps heat into the space), but this package may be simply electric resistance heat elements (large coils which get hot and are in the air stream). I suspect the latter, but can't say right now.

I am surprised that the labeling on the unit does not state that amount (kg) of refrigerant 410A the unit contains and that it does not give the rating in BTU/h. Are there other labels on this equipment?

**EDIT**

Look at the information labels on the outside unit. That will probably give you insight into whether this is a heat pump or just an a/c.

Comment: He's taken a picture of the air handler only.  It has a coil in it, so it's marked with the refrigerant type and PSI rating.  The amount and other info would be posted on the plate of the outside compressor unit.