# CT80 Thermostat Wiring Diagram Selection

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

Which terminal should the brown wire be connected to the [RadioThermostat CT80](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjuzdX0jODgAhWFUt8KHeijBo8QFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.homedepot-static.com%2Fcatalog%2FpdfImages%2Fb9%2Fb9fd998c-6d95-4779-9a40-79e487519a3d.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2shpf2Z-kebO1ZbeUjbNNc)?  The original thermostat was wired as depicted:

[image]

The brown wire is connected to terminal E  (not F).

As I understand it:

- BRN => ? Terminal CT80 Radio thermostat
- YEL => Y Terminal CT 80
- GRN => G Terminal CT 80
- WHT => W Terminal CT 80
- RED => R Terminal CT 80
- BLU => C Terminal CT 80
- ORANGE => O Terminal CT 80

As I understand it, [the brown why controls the Emergency heat relay](http://www.wifithermostatreviews.com/the-thermostat-wiring-color-code-guide/).   Not one of the seven diagrams has an E-Wire.

[image]

## QUESTION

- Is it possible to select one of the seven schemes based on the first photo?
- Where terminal should the brown 'E' be wired in the CT80?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the air handler end?

Comment: I'd have to return to the site to snap photos.  The first photo is of the very old thermostat and I would think that the labeling of the colors is correct?  Maybe the Brown wire should be innervated by terminal W2 on the CT80?

Comment: I hate to say this, but you really need to look at the documentation of the old thermostat and find out what "E" does.  The way thermostat wiring is labeled  isn't *perfectly* standardized when it comes to more obscure functions of heat pumps.  Find out what E meant to the old 'stat.

Comment: @Harper I think you are right.  Unfortunately for me this project is inherited and the gear pre-dates the internet.  If I can find more on the old thermostat I will update the post.